# Extracting a single word from a vector of strings in R

Tags: r, string, stringr

Say I have a vector of strings like the one below and I want to create a logical vector that contains TRUE if the words 'white','bull', or 'tiger' appear (note not whitetip) in the string and FALSE if they do not. How do i go about doing this in R? I've attempted to use stringr's str_detect() but the result gives a TRUE to 'whitetip' (and I don't know how to use str_detect() for each category...i.e. i would have to create multiple logical vectors -1 for each of my 3 categories of white tiger and bull). Any help would be fantastic, thank you!

```
string<-c("tiger?", "thought to involve a 2.7 m [9'], 400-kb bull",
    "4 m to 5 m [13' to 16.5'] white", "oceanic whitetip shark, 2.5 to 3m", 
    "white","white","bull","white","oceanic whitetip shark, 2.5m","tiger",
    "white, >6'","bull, 6'")
```

Comment: Look like your quotes are all a mess for your sample input. That's not a valid R statement. Can you also be clear on what the desired output for the sample vector is. You can match word boundaries in a regular expression with `\b` so maybe you should include that. What code exactly did you attempt to use?

Comment: ok here is the proper vector:

string<-c("tiger?", "thought to involve a 2.7 m [9'], 400-kb bull", "4 m to 5 m [13' to 16.5'] white", "oceanic whitetip shark, 2.5 to 3m", "white","white","bull","white","oceanic whitetip shark, 2.5m","tiger", "white, >6'","bull, 6'")

and I tried

str_detect(string, "bull")
str_detect(string, "tiger")
str_detect(string, "white")

thanks!!

Comment: I also tried akrun's and it only provided the result of TRUE if and only if 'white' 'bull' or 'tiger' were the only characters in the value (so it returns a FALSE for tiger? for example)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way you could match all the strings

```
sapply(c("white","bull","tiger"), function(x) {
    grepl(paste0("\\b",x,"\\b"), string)
})
```

This gives

```
      white  bull tiger
 [1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  # tiger?
 [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  # thought to involve a 2.7 m [9'], 400-kb bull
 [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  # 4 m to 5 m [13' to 16.5'] white
 [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  # oceanic whitetip shark, 2.5 to 3m
 [5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  # white
 [6,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  # white
 [7,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  # bull
 [8,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  # white
 [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  # oceanic whitetip shark, 2.5m
[10,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  # tiger
[11,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  # white, >6'
[12,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  # bull, 6'
```

Comment: Is there a way to extract 'bull' 'tiger' and 'white' from the original vector (named string). For example:

"thought to involve a 2.7 m [9'], 400-kb bull" I would want to get just "bull"

I tried str_extract(string, "[a-z]+")

-it does not return "bull" for "thought to involve a 2.7 m [9'], 400-kb bull"  but it does work for "tiger?", "white, >6" and "bull, 6" (returning tiger, white, and bull respectively). Thanks again everybody!

Comment: If the `grepl()` for "bull" returns `TRUE`, then you know it's in there. Why do you need to "extract" it? I don't understand.

Comment: I would like a vector that is white bull or tiger so i can summarize by group for a different variable not shown here (number of shark attacks)

Comment: @CyrusM sounds like you should accept this answer and ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

If you need to extract the relevant word, you could use `stringr::str_extract`:

```
str_extract(string, "\\b(bull|tiger|white)\\b")

# [1] "tiger" "bull"  "white" NA      "white" "white" "bull"  "white" NA     
#[10] "tiger" "white" "bull"
```